# How to render the shadow of an invisible object?

Tags: rendering, light

Say I wanted to make a render of a ghost. The ghost must be invisible to the camera, but it must still cast a shadow on the ground. How can I block light from passing though an object that is invisible?

[image: Stock photo for example.]

Answer (score 4):

If you are using cycles you just have to disable camera visibility.

[image]

[image]

Alternatively you can make a shader that uses the camera ray as a mix factor for your figure's shader and a transparent one. The camera will not see the object but it will still cast a shadow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Eevee. Give your object a tranparent shader, and set the blend mode to 'Alpha Blend' or 'Alpha Clip' in the materials tab. Make sure to keep the shadow mode set to 'Opaque'.[image: example]

You can't control the opacity of the shadows with this method, but it works for most cases. It also gets rid of the black square problem at intersections.